# C++ how to deal with unused parameters returned by std::to_chars

Tags: c++

I use std::to_chars for a conversion as proposed by the documentation and would

```
unsigned int value = 42;
std::string str(16, '0');
auto [ptr, ec] = std::to_chars(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), value, 16);

return str;
```

this works, but I get

> warning: structured binding declaration set but not used
> [-Wunused-but-set-variable]

which I expect, as I don't use the variables and just need the alterations of the string. How to deal with the warnings, other than ignoring it?

Comment: `auto [ptr, ec] = std::to_chars(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), value, 16);` -> `std::to_chars(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), value, 16);`?

Comment: Use `_` for unwanted variables, or `std::ignore`.

Comment: don't you need to use `ptr` to truncate `str` to the correct length? Probably worth checking `ec` too?

Answer (score 2):

You can use C++17 attribute `[[maybe_unused]]` to suppress the warning

```
 [[maybe_unused]] auto [ptr, ec] = 
   std::to_chars(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), value, 16);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oMzqsrjPh)